# Can I use wired ethernet and wireless Wifi simultaneously?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking, lan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use Wireless and Wired connections at the same time](https://superuser.com/questions/67408/use-wireless-and-wired-connections-at-the-same-time)

My laptop has a LAN socket and Wifi radio. When I insert a cable to connect to another computer for data transfer and sharing resources, the Wifi stays on and connected, but does not work. The LAN takes over completely!

How to tell Firefox to use the Wifi connection for browsing and not the LAN?

I am running Windows XP SP2.

Comment: Why are you plugging in the LAN cable if not to use the LAN for an internet connection?  Better question: what are you plugging it in to?  A router, switch, directly to another machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use something like [ForceBindIP](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) to force Firefox to bind to the WLAN adapter's address.

Comment: I guess this would be a perfect answer at http://superuser.com/questions/67408/use-wireless-and-wired-connections-at-the-same-time (if you agree it's a duplicate).

Comment: (And now that I guess you agreed it's a duplicate, let's close it? Cheers!)