# How can I use simultaneous wifi and ethernet connections to dodge the man?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

At work we have web monitoring services that give the boss a printout of all your slack-off espn.com viewing.  I want to be able to circumvent this.  I have a Droid X with a mobile hotspot which can act as a WiFi router so I can surf the web over the cellular 3G.  However, the software I use for work requires that I use the company Ethernet a lot.  So I can't just unplug the cable.  And it would look suspicious if I were unplugging it and plugging it back in all the time.

So I see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/67408/use-wireless-and-wired-connections-at-the-same-time) that you can have WiFi and Ethernet enabled simultaneously.  From that text I think I understand how I can hook everything up, and force the browser to use a selected IP.  What I'm unclear about is the sentence "all DNS requests will go through the "gateway" address, so only set a gateway for your main(general web browsing) connection"  Does this mean that all web browsing will still get routed through the gateway, and thus still detectable by the man?  Thoughts?

Comment: Your username is highly appropriate for your first question here. Welcome to SuperUser!

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could manage this, your IT department would probably figure it out pretty quickly, especially after you get your computer infected from bypassing your network's security. Not to mention the fact that you would likely need admin credentials to make some of the necessary changes. Pursuing this will get you fired faster than any "slack-off espn viewing"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it is possible with Android but you might consider an application which enables you to remote desktop to your Android phone, so that you are effectively browsing on the phone but from your desktop machine with the phone browsing using it's own 3G internet connection?

Admittedly this will give you a tiny screen, better than nothing or losing your job? 8-)

Answer (score 0):

DNS requests are communications which translate names to IP addresses. When you type, let's say "http://www.espn.com" in your browser, the browser asks the system to find out the IP address associated with www.espn.com. The system will talk the DNS (Nameserver) configured in your network settings. The system will go through the default Gateway (also set up in network configuration) to reach the DNS. If you have DNS set up on all your network interfaces, the first available one will be used. If you have DNS only on your WiFi interface, only that will be used.

It's simple. ;)